# R: creating factor using data from multiple columns

Tags: r, refactoring, grouping, multiple-columns

I want to create a column that codes for whether patients have had a comorbid diagnosis of depression or not. Problem is, the diagnosis can be recorded in one of 4 columns:

- ComorbidDiagnosis;
- OtherDiagnosis;
- DischargeDiagnosis;
- OtherDischargeDiagnosis.

I've been using

```
levels(dataframe$ynDepression)[levels(dataframe$ComorbidDiagnosis)=="Depression"]<-"Yes"
```

for all 4 columns but I don't know how to code those who don't have a diagnosis in any of the columns. I tried:

```
levels(dataframe$ynDepression)[levels(dataframe$DischOtherDiagnosis &
   dataframe$OtherDiagnosis & 
   dataframe$ComorbidDiagnosis & 
   dataframe$DischComorbidDiagnosis)==""]<-"No"
```

I also tried using && instead but it didn't work. Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried uploading an image of some example data but I don't have enough reputations to upload images yet. I'll try to put an example here but might not work:

Patient ID   PrimaryDiagnosis   OtherDiagnosis   ComorbidDiagnosis

1. _________AN__________Depression
2. _________AN
3. _________AN__________Depression______PTSD
4. _________AN_________________________Depression

Comment: Please provide example input data.

Answer (score 0):

What's inside the `[]` must be (transformable to) a boolean for the subset to work. For example:

```
x<-1:5
x[x>3]
#4 5
x>3
# F F F T T
```

works because the condition is a boolean vector. Sometimes, the booleanship can be implicite, like in `dataframe[,"var"]` which means `dataframe[,colnames(dataframe)=="var"]` but R must be able to make it a boolean somehow.

> **EDIT :** As pointed out by beginneR, you can also subset with something like `df[,c(1,3)]`, which is numeric but works the same way as `df[,"var"]`. I like to see that kind of subset as implicit booleans as it enables a yes/no choice but you may very well not agree and only consider that they enable R to select columns and rows.

In your case, the conditions you use are invalid (`dataframe$OtherDiagnosis`for example).

You would need something like `rowSums(df[,c("var1","var2","var3")]=="")==3`, which is a valid condition.

Comment: I can't use R where I am so I couldn't check for errors in my code. That's why I made it minimal but if there is one yet, please tell me and I'll correct it.

Comment: Using logicals for the subset is one option, but not the only way to subset. You can also use indices, in your example you could do: `x[c(4,5)]` if you wanted the elements 4 and 5 of x to be returned. the same works if you use `x[which(x>3)]`.

Comment: You're right but I feel like it can be seen as an implicite boolean too, with the same principle as the exemple I used with `df[,"var"]`.

Comment: Eventually I was able to use R and saw my answer was incorrect. This edit make it better.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I managed to group using:
`df$var5<-ifelse(rowSums(All[,c("var1","var2","var3", "var4")]=="")==4,1, #no diagnosis is coded as 1
                  
ifelse(rowSums(All[,c("var1","var2","var3", "var4")]=="x")>=1,2,NA)) #diagnosis of x is coded as 2`